# In Spring Security 5 why do AuthorizedClientManager and ExchangeFilterFunction both require an authorizationFailureHandler?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing a resource server in Spring and need to configure a WebClient in order to access downstream data from other APIs. That WebClient needs to negotiate a client credentials OAuth2 flow. Fairly typical stuff. What I find confusing is the following:

When configuring a WebClient for this purpose, I first define an appropriate `ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager`. Then I define an appropriate `ExchangeFilterFunction`, initializing it with my client manager. According to Spring's docs (and confirming by looking at the source code) when initializing the filter function in this manner, I still need to explicitly set an `authorizationFailureHandler` for it even though the client manager has effectively the same `authorizationFailureHandler` automatically configured.

Am I missing something about why this was done? Maybe this is a question for the Spring Security guys.

Here is my code:

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClientForSomeDownstreamAPI(
                       ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                       ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                    clientRegistrationRepository,
                    authorizedClientService);
      
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build());

    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler authorizationFailureHandler = 
            new RemoveAuthorizedClientReactiveOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler(
                (clientRegistrationId, principal, attributes) -> 
                        authorizedClientService.removeAuthorizedClient(
                        clientRegistrationId, principal.getName()));

    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
            new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);

    //for some reason the filter function and the client manager both need a failure handler
    oauth.setAuthorizationFailureHandler(authorizationFailureHandler);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("redacted");

    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauth)
            .clientConnector(createClientConnectorWithLogging())
            .baseUrl("redacted")
            .build();
}
```

Spring's `AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` (geez what a mouthful) configures a failure handler automatically, using a reference to the passed-in `authorizedClientService` as seen in the below code snippet (taken from the source code).

```
public AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        Assert.notNull(clientRegistrationRepository, "clientRegistrationRepository cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(authorizedClientService, "authorizedClientService cannot be null");
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
        this.authorizedClientService = authorizedClientService;
        this.authorizationSuccessHandler = (authorizedClient, principal, attributes) -> authorizedClientService
                .saveAuthorizedClient(authorizedClient, principal);
        this.authorizationFailureHandler = new RemoveAuthorizedClientReactiveOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler(
                (clientRegistrationId, principal, attributes) -> this.authorizedClientService
                        .removeAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId, principal.getName()));
    }
```

But the `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` constructor I am using (that takes a client manager as an argument) needs me to subsequently set the failure handler explicitly. See the following snippet from the JavaDoc:

```
/**
     * When this constructor is used, authentication (HTTP 401) and authorization (HTTP
     * 403) failures returned from a OAuth 2.0 Resource Server will <em>NOT</em> be
     * forwarded to a {@link ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler}. Therefore, future
     * requests to the Resource Server will most likely use the same (most likely invalid)
     * token, resulting in the same errors returned from the Resource Server. It is
     * recommended to configure a
     * {@link RemoveAuthorizedClientReactiveOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler} via
     * {@link #setAuthorizationFailureHandler(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler)}
     * so that authentication and authorization failures returned from a Resource Server
     * will result in removing the authorized client, so that a new token is retrieved for
     * future requests.
*/
```

What makes this interesting is that the other filter function constructor *does* create an `authorizationFailureHandler` and it's darn near the same as what the client manager automatically creates. See here:

```
public ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler authorizationFailureHandler = new RemoveAuthorizedClientReactiveOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler(
                (clientRegistrationId, principal, attributes) -> authorizedClientRepository.removeAuthorizedClient(
                        clientRegistrationId, principal,
                        (ServerWebExchange) attributes.get(ServerWebExchange.class.getName())));
        this.authorizedClientManager = createDefaultAuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository,
                authorizedClientRepository, authorizationFailureHandler);
        this.clientResponseHandler = new AuthorizationFailureForwarder(authorizationFailureHandler);
        this.defaultAuthorizedClientManager = true;
    }
```

I understand that the client manager does **not** expose its `authorizationFailureHandler` by way of a getter so the filter function constructor I am invoking cannot just refer to it. But what's the deal with all of that? It doesn't feel right to have two failure handlers doing the same thing to the same `authorizedClientService` so I must be missing something.

I am using Spring Boot 2.4.1 with Spring Security 5.4.2.

Comment: I think much of the context is provided in the issue(s) that resulted in that constructor. There was quite a bit of discussion that went into it. One related issue is [#7699](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7699). Does that help answer your question?